# Add ad users to a group (First Name, Last Name)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am not an admin, but have been given rights to add users to a specific AD Group.

I have been given a list of users to add to this AD Group:

1. This list has the user's "Firstname, Lastname"
2. This list of users already exist in Active Directory, and just need to be made member of the specific AD Group.

Is there a way to bulk import them in using their first/last name?

I have the following steps, but it fails to find the users (probably because it is looking for adnames, instead of firstname, last name).

a. Create a csv with 2 columns, user name, and group.

b. At PowerShell

```
Import-CSV listofusers.csv | Foreach-Object {Add-ADGroupmember -Identity $_.group -Members $_.name}
```

If you do not have the ActiveDirectory module loaded you can also use this alternative:

```
Import-CSV listofusers.csv | Foreach-Object {dsmod group $_.group -addmbr $_.user}
```

Comment: So you're working with a CSV of users' first/last name and desired group?  Or just names?  Your comment about them already being in AD and needing to bulk import them is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The `-Members` parameter of `Add-ADGroupMember` expects a PowerShell AD object (object, user, computer, ...), a GUID, SID, or sAMAccountName. I assume your "Lastname, Firstname" equals none of these.

I suggest you to first find the user in Active Directory, using `Get-ADUser` with an appropriate filter, and use this object for the value of `-Members`.

The following example should work, if Lastname and Firstname is a proper column in your CSV.

```
Import-CSV listofusers.csv | Foreach-Object -Process {
    $GivenName = $_.Firstname
    $Surname = $_.Lastname
    $User = Get-ADUser -Filter {
        (GivenName -eq $GivenName) -and (Surname -eq $Surname)
    }
    Add-ADGroupmember -Identity $_.group -Members $User
}
```

Please note, that I'd reccomend you to change the source file, in such a way that it provides a unique identifier (DN, UPN, sAMaccountName, ...). If you have to users of the same last- and firstname, you might assign privilges to the wrong user.